# vue-carousel goToPage to programmatically change to selected page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, carousel, vue-component, laravel-5.7

I'm passing a collection of locations into vue-carousel. I'm using the same collection in a couple of other places on the page, emitting the selected location to the root, which is where the locations and selected location are stored, in an eventHub.

The tricky part was getting the carousel to move to the right page - I'm showing three locations at a time in larger viewports and just one on smaller, using the perPageCustom option. I create keys in the api in laravel and based on the size of the window, I'm moving to the right page and it all works, but when it loads I get an error because the ref doesn't exist when the watcher first fires off. I know that's the issue, but I'm not sure how to have a watcher for when the location changes, that doesn't watch when the page loads... perhaps using the mount?

My component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h3>Locations ({{locations.length}})</h3>
        <p class="lead">Serving California in the greater Sacramento and Los Angeles areas.</p>
        <carousel v-if="locations.length > 0" ref="locations-carousel" :scrollPerPage="true" :perPage="1" :perPageCustom="[[480, 1], [768, 3]]" v-on:pageChange="pageChange">
          <slide v-for="loc in locations" :key="loc.id">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" v-bind:class="{ closest: loc.is_closest,  active: loc.id == location.id }">
              <img v-on:click="changeLocation(loc.id)" v-if="loc.is_comingsoon === 0" class="card-img-top" :src="'/assets/images/location_'+loc.pathname+'.jpg'" alt="Card image cap">
              <img v-on:click="changeLocation(loc.id)" v-if="loc.is_comingsoon === 1" class="card-img-top" :src="'/assets/images/coming-soon.png'" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title" v-on:click="changeLocation(loc.id)">{{ loc.name }}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ loc.address }}<br>{{ loc.city_name }}<br>{{ loc.phone | phone }}</p>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Location Buttons">
                  <a class="btn btn-outline btn-default" :href="'tel:'+ loc.phone"><font-awesome-icon icon="phone"></font-awesome-icon> call</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-outline btn-default" :href="loc.map"><font-awesome-icon icon="globe"></font-awesome-icon> map</a>
                  <a class="btn btn-outline btn-default" v-on:click="changeLocation(loc)" v-bind:class="{ active: loc.id == location.id }"><font-awesome-icon icon="star"></font-awesome-icon> pick</a>
                </div>
                <p class="card-text">{{ loc.note }}</p>
                <span class="badge badge-closest" v-if="loc.is_closest"><font-awesome-icon icon="map-marker"></font-awesome-icon> closest detected</span>
                <span class="badge badge-active" v-if="loc.id == location.id"><font-awesome-icon icon="star"></font-awesome-icon> selected <font-awesome-icon icon="angle-double-down" :style="{ color: 'white' }"></font-awesome-icon></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </slide>
        </carousel>
        <font-awesome-icon icon="spinner" size="lg" v-if="locations.length < 1"></font-awesome-icon>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    Vue.filter('phone', function (phone) {
        return phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
                    .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
    });
    import { Carousel, Slide } from 'vue-carousel';
    var axios = require("axios");
    export default {
        name: 'locations-carousel',
        props: ['location', 'pg', 'locations'],
        components: {
            Carousel,
            Slide
        },
        data() {
            return {
                debounce: null,
                subs: {},
                clear: 0
            };
        },
        watch: { 
            location: function(newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
                console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
                console.log('key: '+this.location.key);
                if( window.innerWidth > 481 ) {
                    if( this.location.pg == 1 ) {
                        this.$refs['locations-carousel'].goToPage(-0);
                    } else {
                        this.$refs['locations-carousel'].goToPage(1);
                    }   
                } else {
                    this.$refs['locations-carousel'].goToPage(this.location.key);
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            pageChange(i){ 
                console.log('current Index', i); 
            },
            changeLocation(location) {
                this.$eventHub.$emit('location-loaded', location);              
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

The error I'm getting:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "location": "TypeError: 
Cannot read property 'goToPage' of undefined"

found in

---> <LocationsCarousel> at resources/assets/js/components/LocationsCarousel.vue
   <Root>

TypeError: Cannot read property 'goToPage' of undefined
at VueComponent.location (app.js?v=0.1:53288)
at Watcher.run (app.js?v=0.1:3937)
at flushSchedulerQueue (app.js?v=0.1:3685)
at Array.<anonymous> (app.js?v=0.1:2541)
at flushCallbacks (app.js?v=0.1:2462)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can check first to see if `this.$refs['locations-carousel']` exists before accessing its properties/methods ..

```
watch: {
  location: function(newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
    console.log('Prop changed: ', newVal, ' | was: ', oldVal)
    console.log('key: ' + this.location.key);
    const locationsCarousel = this.$refs['locations-carousel']
    if (window.innerWidth > 481) {
      if (this.location.pg == 1) {
        locationsCarousel && locationsCarousel.goToPage(-0);
      } else {
        locationsCarousel && locationsCarousel.goToPage(1);
      }
    } else {
      locationsCarousel && locationsCarousel.goToPage(this.location.key);
    }
  }
},
```